# Vue warn: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

When I use axios I got this error:

[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

```
export default {
        methods: {
            loadUsers(){
                axios.get("api/user").then(data  => (this.users = data));
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.loadUsers();
        }
    }
```

Routes:
 api.php

```
Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);
```

Controller:
API/UserController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        return User::latest()->paginate(5);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `axios` is `undefined`, did you import it?

Comment: Ohh I import this: `import {AxiosInstance as axios} from "axios";` When remove this, there has no error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import Axios first:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default { 
    // ... axios.get will work now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error .this error comes due to the vue cannot identify the get property which is belongs to the 'vue-resource' package so my recommendation is need to import package it will help to resolse this issue follow below step

first check 'vue-resource' installed on your project
otherwise install it

npm install vue-resource

In main.js file include this

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource);